OR-Tools library, CP-SAT Solver. With a large number of workers (num_search_workers), model calculation does not stop after calling stop_search
I'm solving a standard job shop scheduling problem. The launch occurs through an airflow in docker container.
Here are the machine parameters:

CPU: Intel Xeon Gold 6230
RAM: more than 300 GB

When the number of operations becomes about 1000 per calculation, the solver crashes with a memory error (Task exited with return code -9), without finding a solution (increasing the amount of RAM doesn't help).  During testing, it was revealed that the problem can be solved by specifying a large number of workers (from 100) in the model settings. But the more you increase the number of workers, the greater the likelihood that after finding the required number of solutions or stopping on the timer, calling stop_search, the model will not exit, but everything will simply freeze.
Here how my callback looks like:
class ObjectiveEarlyStopping(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    def __init__(self, solution_count_limit=GlobalVariables.SOLUTION_COUNT_LIMIT,
                 max_execution_time=GlobalVariables.MIN_EXECUTION_WORKTIME):
        super(ObjectiveEarlyStopping, self).__init__()
        self._solution_count = 0
        self._solution_limit = max(2, solution_count_limit)
        self._max_execution_time = max_execution_time

        self._logger = LocalLogger().logger
        self._timer = None
        self._no_improvement_timer_limit = GlobalVariables.SOLUTION_IMPROVEMENT_TIMEOUT_SEC
        self._total_execution_time = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        self._solution_count += 1
        self._logger.info(f"Feasible solution #{self._solution_count} found.")

        if self._solution_count >= self._solution_limit:
            self._logger.debug(f"Stopping search after {self._solution_count} solutions")
            self._stop_timer()
            self._timer = None
            self._logger.info(f"Stopping search __3")
            super().StopSearch()
            self._logger.info(f"Stopping search __4")
        else:
            self._reset_timer()

    def _stop_timer(self):
        if self._timer:
            self._timer.cancel()

    def _reset_timer(self):
        self._total_execution_time += self._no_improvement_timer_limit
        self._stop_timer()
        self._timer = Timer(self._no_improvement_timer_limit, self.StopSearch)
        self._timer.start()

    def StopSearch(self):
        self._logger.debug(f"{self._no_improvement_timer_limit} seconds without improvement")
        self._timer = None

        if self._solution_count >= 2 or self._total_execution_time > self._max_execution_time:
            self._logger.info(f"Stopping search __1")
            super().StopSearch()
            self._logger.info(f"Stopping search __2")
        else:
            self._logger.debug("Not enough solutions, continue search")
            self._reset_timer()

For example here how my logs look like:
[2024-04-12, 13:46:17 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:46:17 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:46:22 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:46:22 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:46:26 UTC] {solution_callback.py:23} INFO - Feasible solution #1 found.
[2024-04-12, 13:46:27 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:46:27 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:46:29 UTC] {solution_callback.py:23} INFO - Feasible solution #2 found.
[2024-04-12, 13:46:32 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:46:32 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:46:37 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:46:37 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:46:42 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:46:43 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:46:48 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:46:48 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:46:49 UTC] {solution_callback.py:46} DEBUG - 20 seconds without improvement
[2024-04-12, 13:46:49 UTC] {solution_callback.py:50} INFO - Stopping search __1
[2024-04-12, 13:46:49 UTC] {solution_callback.py:52} INFO - Stopping search __2
[2024-04-12, 13:46:53 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:46:53 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:46:58 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:46:58 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:47:03 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:47:03 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:47:08 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:47:08 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:47:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:47:13 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:47:18 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:47:18 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]
[2024-04-12, 13:47:23 UTC] {taskinstance.py:844} DEBUG - Refreshing TaskInstance <TaskInstance: production_capacity_balancing.production_shceduling_optimizer manual__2024-04-12T13:34:02+00:00 [running]> from DB
[2024-04-12, 13:47:23 UTC] {job.py:216} DEBUG - [heartbeat]

And than this heartbeat message will be shown until I stop it manually.
I also tried replacing super().StopSearch() with super().stop_search(), which has a has_response() check call, but that didn't help either.
Please tell me how to avoid freezing when exiting the model?
And what is the best way to select the number of workers depending on the input parameters?

First: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/troubleshooting.md#improving-performance-with-multiple-workers
I recommend using 32 to 64 workers, and no more that the number of cores.
Each worker you add roughly adds one more copy of the model.
The best way to help the solver is to give a feasible solution as a hint, if building one is easy.
Please also indicate which version you are using.
Finally, for very large models, sometimes, we do not check the time limit often enough. Still, we made good progress in those checks. This is why I asked for the version.

I'm using version 9.9.
I already tried to test with a small number of workers (from 1 to 64), and in such cases, there was a crash due to a lack of memory.

The processor has 20 cores with 40 threads.
I know that each new worker adds one more copy of the model, so I decided to increase the number of workers significantly. The model manages to find a solution before too much memory consumption occurs. This helped with solving the memory error, but а new error appeared (freezing). if this is the wrong solution, please tell me how to solve the memory problem.

By the way, when I test locally on my Mac with a 10-core CPU of less power and only 32 GB of RAM, the solution is found faster than on a more powerful server. Same input parameters (the number of workers is not specified or less than 50). When I set more workers, the speed of the solution search on the Mac decreases, but on the server, it increases. Only with more than 300 workers, the search for solutions is getting worse

if you use 8x the number of cores, the best cores are 8x slower.

We made a full feasible hint for the model "The solution hint is complete and is feasible." but for some reason after the presolve, the following message is displayed:
"The solution hint is complete, but it is infeasible! we will try to repair it."
What would you recommend to do to avoid breaking the hint when presolve?

which version ? We fixed a lot of corner case in 9.10. The last option is to set: keep_all_feasible_solutions_in_presolve to true
